# using MAX function in HQL

Tags: hql

The below query has some issues. The subquery that I use here runs without any errors when run separately. However if I run the whole query below it ends in error.
"Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 13:30 cannot recognize input near 'select' 'max' '(' in expression specification"

```
select acct_num from table1
where ind = 'Y'
      and b = (select max(yr_mth_num) from table2)
      and st_dt = (select cast(max(st_dt) as date) from table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.acct_num 
FROM table1 T1 
LEFT SEMI JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        max(yr_mth_num) as max_yr_mth_num,
        cast(max(st_dt) as date) as max_st_dt
     FROM table2) T2
ON T1.b = T2.max_yr_mth_num
AND T1.st_dt = T2.max_st_dt
AND T1.ind = 'Y'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It works... individually.. however the query I pasted is only a small part of the huge one am dealing with.. I will try to incorporate similar approach on teh whole.. thanks a lot once again.

Comment: The main reason your original query was failing is because those SELECT subqueries don't return numbers, they return arrays, and you can't test for equality between a single number and an array. You can try and do an array_contains for those lines in your "where" clause, but I changed it to left semi join because then you only have to compute the max of all those columns once. Good luck on getting it to work for your entire query!

Comment: I incorporated the above concept on the whole query and its working!! Thanks for clarifying my doubt..